# openldap alternative to modifying core schema syntax

Tags: ldap, openldap, schema, syntax, attributes

I have an application that stores contacts in OpenLDAP. It uses the `c` attribute to store a string describing a country name. The syntax of `c` only allows a two-letter country code, but the application uses full country names. Therefore the attribute it *should* be using is `co`, or
`friendlyCountryName`. Unfortunately I cannot change this application. (It's Mozilla).

I am looking for a way to make this work. I can, of course, change the schema definition of `c` to that of `co`, but that seems bad practice. I could also disable schema checking, but that is even worse.

I have also tried using the rwm overlay to map `c` onto `co`, which works (as in: client saves `c`, database contains `co`), but then the syntax of `c` is still enforced, so that doesn't work.

So, the best option I have now is to change the syntax of `c` in the core schema. But I am curious: are there better ways to work around this?

Comment: By Mozilla do you mean [Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/thunderbird)?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the official Mozilla schema spec, which can be found [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Mozilla_LDAP_Address_Book_Schema)

Answer (score 0):

If your LDAP server is configured with the [`mozillaAbPersonAlpha`](https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Mozilla_LDAP_Address_Book_Schema) schema, you can tack the AUX `objectClass: mozillaAbPersonAlpha` onto your entries (provided they have `cn`) and then use the `mozillaHomeCountryName` attribute.

Comment: How will that help? Thunderbird will still use the `c` attribute for storing the country name. It's not that _I_ need a place to store the full country name, I need a way to let Thunderbird store the full country name in the attribute that it uses for that (which is `c`).